# Solving system of polynomial matrix equations over $\Bbb Z_2$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, finite-fields, matrix-equations

Let $A, B, C, D$ be $4 \times 4$ matrices over $\mathbb{Z}_2$.

Suppose they satisfy
\begin{equation}
    \begin{cases}
      A^2+ BC+ BCA+ ABC+ A= I_4\\
      AB+ BCB+ ABD=0_{4 \times 4} \\
      CA+ DCA+ CBC= 0_{4 \times 4} \\
      DCB+ CBD= I_4
    \end{cases}\,.
\end{equation}

Does anyone have an idea on how to find matrices $A, B, C, D$ either theoretically or numerically? I'm thinking that we can find a solution since there are four equations and four unknowns.

Hints would suffice. Thank you so much.

Edit: I found out that the 148 solutions is not yet the total number of complete solutions. To possibly decrease the number of solutions I added another constraint:

$$\sum_{k=1}^4\sum_{l=1}^4 A_{1,k}A_{k,l}A_{l,1}+ \sum_{k=1}^4\sum_{l=1}^4 B_{1,k}C_{k,l}A_{l,1}+ \sum_{k=1}^4\sum_{l=1}^4 A_{1,k}B_{k,l}C_{l,1}+ \sum_{k=1}^4\sum_{l=1}^4 B_{1,k}D_{k,l}C_{l,1}=2Y_{5,1,1}.$$

I added this constraint to the last part of the code:

```
proc optmodel;
   num n = 4;
   set ROWS = 1..n;
   set COLS = ROWS;
   set CELLS = ROWS cross COLS;

   var A {CELLS} binary;
   var B {CELLS} binary;
   var C {CELLS} binary;
   var D {CELLS} binary;

   var Y {1..5, CELLS} >= 0 integer;
   
    /* M[i,j,k] = A[i,k]*A[k,j] */
   var M {1..n, 1..n, 1..n} binary;
   con Mcon1 {i in 1..n, j in 1..n, k in 1..n}:
      M[i,j,k] <= A[i,k];
   con Mcon2 {i in 1..n, j in 1..n, k in 1..n}:
      M[i,j,k] <= A[k,j];
   con Mcon3 {i in 1..n, j in 1..n, k in 1..n}:
      M[i,j,k] >= A[i,k] + A[k,j] - 1;
      
    /* X[i,j,k] = B[i,k]*C[k,j] */
   var X {1..n, 1..n, 1..n} binary;
   con Xcon1 {i in 1..n, j in 1..n, k in 1..n}:
      X[i,j,k] <= B[i,k];
   con Xcon2 {i in 1..n, j in 1..n, k in 1..n}:
      X[i,j,k] <= C[k,j];
   con Xcon3 {i in 1..n, j in 1..n, k in 1..n}:
      X[i,j,k] >= B[i,k] + C[k,j] - 1;
      
     /* O[i,j,k,l] = B[i,k]*C[k,l]*A[l,j] */
   var O {1..n, 1..n, 1..n, 1..n} binary;
   con Ocon1 {i in 1..n, j in 1..n, k in 1..n, l in 1..n}:
      O[i,j,k,l] <= B[i,k];
   con Ocon2 {i in 1..n, j in 1..n, k in 1..n, l in 1..n}:
      O[i,j,k,l] <= C[k,l];
   con Ocon3 {i in 1..n, j in 1..n, k in 1..n, l in 1..n}:
      O[i,j,k,l] <= A[l,j];   
   con Ocon4 {i in 1..n, j in 1..n, k in 1..n, l in 1..n}:
      O[i,j,k,l] >= B[i,k]+C[k,l]+A[l,j] - 2;  
      
      /* P[i,j,k,l] = A[i,k]*B[k,l]*C[l,j] */
   var P {1..n, 1..n, 1..n, 1..n} binary;
   con Pcon1 {i in 1..n, j in 1..n, k in 1..n, l in 1..n}:
      P[i,j,k,l] <= A[i,k];
   con Pcon2 {i in 1..n, j in 1..n, k in 1..n, l in 1..n}:
      P[i,j,k,l] <= B[k,l];
   con Pcon3 {i in 1..n, j in 1..n, k in 1..n, l in 1..n}:
      P[i,j,k,l] <= C[l,j];   
   con Pcon4 {i in 1..n, j in 1..n, k in 1..n, l in 1..n}:
      P[i,j,k,l] >= A[i,k]+B[k,l]+C[l,j] - 2;

   /* A^2 + BC + BCA + ABC + A = I_4 */
   con Con1 {<i,j> in CELLS}:
      sum {k in 1..n} M[i,j,k] 
    + sum {k in 1..n} X[i,j,k] 
    + sum {k in 1..n, l in 1..n} O[i,j,k,l] 
    + sum {k in 1..n, l in 1..n} P[i,j,k,l]
    + A[i,j] 
   = 2*Y[1,i,j] + (i=j);
   
   /* E[i,j,k] = A[i,k]*B[k,j] */
   var E {1..n, 1..n, 1..n} binary;
   con Econ1 {i in 1..n, j in 1..n, k in 1..n}:
      E[i,j,k] <= A[i,k];
   con Econ2 {i in 1..n, j in 1..n, k in 1..n}:
      E[i,j,k] <= B[k,j];
   con Econ3 {i in 1..n, j in 1..n, k in 1..n}:
      E[i,j,k] >= A[i,k] + B[k,j] - 1;
      
    /* F[i,j,k,l] = B[i,k]*C[k,l]*B[l,j] */
   var F {1..n, 1..n, 1..n, 1..n} binary;
   con Fcon1 {i in 1..n, j in 1..n, k in 1..n, l in 1..n}:
      F[i,j,k,l] <= B[i,k];
   con Fcon2 {i in 1..n, j in 1..n, k in 1..n, l in 1..n}:
      F[i,j,k,l] <= C[k,l];
   con Fcon3 {i in 1..n, j in 1..n, k in 1..n, l in 1..n}:
      F[i,j,k,l] <= B[l,j];   
   con Fcon4 {i in 1..n, j in 1..n, k in 1..n, l in 1..n}:
      F[i,j,k,l] >= B[i,k]+C[k,l]+B[l,j] - 2;
      
      /* G[i,j,k,l] = A[i,k]*B[k,l]*D[l,j] */
   var G {1..n, 1..n, 1..n, 1..n} binary;
   con Gcon1 {i in 1..n, j in 1..n, k in 1..n, l in 1..n}:
      G[i,j,k,l] <= A[i,k];
   con Gcon2 {i in 1..n, j in 1..n, k in 1..n, l in 1..n}:
      G[i,j,k,l] <= B[k,l];
   con Gcon3 {i in 1..n, j in 1..n, k in 1..n, l in 1..n}:
      G[i,j,k,l] <= D[l,j];   
   con Gcon4 {i in 1..n, j in 1..n, k in 1..n, l in 1..n}:
      G[i,j,k,l] >= A[i,k]+B[k,l]+D[l,j] - 2; 

   /* AB + BCB + ABD = 0 */
   con Con2 {<i,j> in CELLS}:
      sum {k in 1..n} E[i,j,k] 
    + sum {k in 1..n, l in 1..n} F[i,j,k,l] 
    + sum {k in 1..n, l in 1..n} G[i,j,k,l]
   = 2*Y[2,i,j];
   
   /* H[i,j,k] = C[i,k]*A[k,j] */
   var H {1..n, 1..n, 1..n} binary;
   con Hcon1 {i in 1..n, j in 1..n, k in 1..n}:
      H[i,j,k] <= C[i,k];
   con Hcon2 {i in 1..n, j in 1..n, k in 1..n}:
      H[i,j,k] <= A[k,j];
   con Hcon3 {i in 1..n, j in 1..n, k in 1..n}:
      H[i,j,k] >= C[i,k] + A[k,j] - 1;
      
    /* Q[i,j,k,l] = D[i,k]*C[k,l]*A[l,j] */
   var Q {1..n, 1..n, 1..n, 1..n} binary;
   con Qcon1 {i in 1..n, j in 1..n, k in 1..n, l in 1..n}:
      Q[i,j,k,l] <= D[i,k];
   con Qcon2 {i in 1..n, j in 1..n, k in 1..n, l in 1..n}:
      Q[i,j,k,l] <= C[k,l];
   con Qcon3 {i in 1..n, j in 1..n, k in 1..n, l in 1..n}:
      Q[i,j,k,l] <= A[l,j];   
   con Qcon4 {i in 1..n, j in 1..n, k in 1..n, l in 1..n}:
      Q[i,j,k,l] >= D[i,k]+C[k,l]+A[l,j] - 2; 
      
    /* R[i,j,k,l] = C[i,k]*B[k,l]*C[l,j] */
   var R {1..n, 1..n, 1..n, 1..n} binary;
   con Rcon1 {i in 1..n, j in 1..n, k in 1..n, l in 1..n}:
      R[i,j,k,l] <= C[i,k];
   con Rcon2 {i in 1..n, j in 1..n, k in 1..n, l in 1..n}:
      R[i,j,k,l] <= B[k,l];
   con Rcon3 {i in 1..n, j in 1..n, k in 1..n, l in 1..n}:
      R[i,j,k,l] <= C[l,j];   
   con Rcon4 {i in 1..n, j in 1..n, k in 1..n, l in 1..n}:
      R[i,j,k,l] >= C[i,k]+B[k,l]+C[l,j] - 2; 

   /* CA + DCA + CBC = 0 */
   con Con3 {<i,j> in CELLS}:
      sum {k in 1..n} H[i,j,k]
    + sum {k in 1..n, l in 1..n} Q[i,j,k,l] 
    + sum {k in 1..n, l in 1..n} R[i,j,k,l]
   = 2*Y[3,i,j];
   
   /* W[i,j,k,l] = D[i,k]*C[k,l]*B[l,j] */
   var W {1..n, 1..n, 1..n, 1..n} binary;
   con Wcon1 {i in 1..n, j in 1..n, k in 1..n, l in 1..n}:
      W[i,j,k,l] <= D[i,k];
   con Wcon2 {i in 1..n, j in 1..n, k in 1..n, l in 1..n}:
      W[i,j,k,l] <= C[k,l];
   con Wcon3 {i in 1..n, j in 1..n, k in 1..n, l in 1..n}:
      W[i,j,k,l] <= B[l,j];   
   con Wcon4 {i in 1..n, j in 1..n, k in 1..n, l in 1..n}:
      W[i,j,k,l] >= D[i,k]+C[k,l]+B[l,j] - 2; 
      
      /* T[i,j,k,l] = C[i,k]*B[k,l]*D[l,j] */
   var T {1..n, 1..n, 1..n, 1..n} binary;
   con Tcon1 {i in 1..n, j in 1..n, k in 1..n, l in 1..n}:
      T[i,j,k,l] <= C[i,k];
   con Tcon2 {i in 1..n, j in 1..n, k in 1..n, l in 1..n}:
      T[i,j,k,l] <= B[k,l];
   con Tcon3 {i in 1..n, j in 1..n, k in 1..n, l in 1..n}:
      T[i,j,k,l] <= D[l,j];   
   con Tcon4 {i in 1..n, j in 1..n, k in 1..n, l in 1..n}:
      T[i,j,k,l] >= C[i,k]+B[k,l]+D[l,j] - 2;

   /* DCB + CBD = I_4 */
   con Con4 {<i,j> in CELLS}:
      sum {k in 1..n, l in 1..n} W[i,j,k,l] 
    + sum {k in 1..n, l in 1..n} T[i,j,k,l]
   = 2*Y[4,i,j] + (i=j);
   
   /* U[1,1,k,l] = A[1,k]*A[k,l]*A[l,1] */
   var U {1..n, 1..n} binary;
   con Ucon1 {k in 1..n, l in 1..n}:
      U[k,l] <= A[1,k];
   con Ucon2 {k in 1..n, l in 1..n}:
      U[k,l] <= A[k,l];
   con Ucon3 {k in 1..n, l in 1..n}:
      U[k,l] <= A[l,1];   
   con Ucon4 {k in 1..n, l in 1..n}:
      U[k,l] >= A[1,k]+A[k,l]+A[l,1] - 2;
      
    /* V[1,1,k,l] = B[1,k]*D[k,l]*C[l,1] */
   var V {1..n, 1..n} binary;
   con Vcon1 {k in 1..n, l in 1..n}:
      V[k,l] <= B[1,k];
   con Vcon2 {k in 1..n, l in 1..n}:
      V[k,l] <= D[k,l];
   con Vcon3 {k in 1..n, l in 1..n}:
      V[k,l] <= C[l,1];   
   con Vcon4 {k in 1..n, l in 1..n}:
      V[k,l] >= B[1,k]+D[k,l]+C[l,1] - 2;  
   
   con 
   sum {k in 1..n, l in 1..n} U[k,l] 
    + sum {k in 1..n, l in 1..n} V[k,l]+ sum {k in 1..n, l in 1..n} O[1,1,k,l] + sum {k in 1..n, l in 1..n} P[1,1,k,l] 
   = 2*Y[5,1,1] ;
   

   solve noobj with milp / maxpoolsols=100 soltype=best;
   create data out(drop=s) from [s]=(1.._NSOL_) {i in 1..n, j in 1..n} <col('A_'||i||''||j)=A[i,j].sol[s]> {i in 1..n, j in 1..n} <col('B'||i||''||j)=B[i,j].sol[s]> {i in 1..n, j in 1..n} <col('C'||i||''||j)=C[i,j].sol[s]> {i in 1..n, j in 1..n} <col('D'||i||'_'||j)=D[i,j].sol[s]>;  
   
   print A;
   print B;
   print C;
   print D;
quit;
```

The software found 100 solutions, but when I checked the output data, it is the same solution replicated 100 times. Is there something wrong with the syntax of the constraint that I added to the code?

Comment: if you want to do it numerically, can you just convert it to a system of 64 equations in 64 unknowns?

Comment: Did you mean $\Bbb F_2$?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo $\mathbb Z_2 = \mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$ is a model for $\mathbb F_2$.

Comment: Does this come from a block matrix equation $\mathcal A\mathcal B = I_8$?

Comment: @azif00 I am totally ignorant on that. My question is — should tag [tag:finite-fields] be added?

Comment: @amsmath yes this is actually a block matrix equation equal to the identity but the form is not $\mathcal{A}\mathcal{B}=I_8$

Comment: @MashedPotato Yeah, I couldn't find such a form. The best I could get is $\mathcal A\mathcal B = (I_4-A-BC+A^2)\oplus I_4$.

Comment: Do you want all solutions, or just *any* solution?

Comment: Hello @Servaes! I want all solutions

Comment: The syntax looks correct, although you could merge the LHS into a single SUM: sum {k in 1..n, l in 1..n} (U[k,l] + V[k,l] + O[1,1,k,l] + P[1,1,k,l]).  Did you get any errors or warnings in the log?

Comment: Another possibility is that A, B, C, and D do not uniquely determine a solution.  I recommend modifying the CREATE DATA statement to output all variables and seeing if there is a difference in some other variable even though A, B, C, and D are the same.

Comment: I know I should get at least two distinct solutions since the solution that you gave is also a solution even with the added constraint

Comment: @RobPratt I checked the other variables as you suggested, and their values are all the same. This time I raised maxpoolsols to 200, and I got 200 solutions but it is the same solution repeated 200 times. I also tried adding another constraint (almost same with the one I added in the question but $j=4$) and still got repeating solutions.

Comment: I’m starting to think that there might be something wrong to the added constraints that makes the software replicate the solutions since I did not encounter this problem before

Comment: OK, I see what is going on.  Before your recent changes, each (A,B,C,D) solution uniquely determines the other variables.  But then you defined 16 new variables Y[5,i,j] and used only one of them.  The other 15 are free to take any value, so you get multiple copies of each (A,B,C,D) solution.  Better to define just one new variable, say Z >= 0 integer, and use it in the RHS of your new constraint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can formulate this as an integer linear programming problem, and here is a feasible solution:
\begin{align}
A&= \begin{pmatrix}
0 &0 &0 &1 \\
1 &0 &1 &0 \\
1 &1 &1 &1 \\
1 &0 &0 &1 \\
\end{pmatrix} \\
B&= \begin{pmatrix}
1 &1 &0 &0 \\
0 &1 &1 &0 \\
1 &0 &1 &1 \\
0 &0 &1 &0 \\
\end{pmatrix} \\
C&= \begin{pmatrix}
1 &1 &0 &1 \\
1 &1 &0 &0 \\
1 &0 &0 &0 \\
1 &0 &1 &0 \\
\end{pmatrix} \\
D&= \begin{pmatrix}
0 &0 &1 &1 \\
0 &0 &0 &1 \\
0 &0 &0 &0 \\
0 &0 &0 &0 \\
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align}
There are 64 constraints, 64 binary decision variables $(A_{i,j},B_{i,j},C_{i,j},D_{i,j})$, and 64 nonnegative integer variables ($Y_{t,i,j}$ for $t\in\{1,2,3,4\}$ and all $(i,j)$).  Explicitly, the constraints  are
\begin{align}
    \sum_{k=1}^n \left(A_{i,k} A_{k,j} 
    + B_{i,k} C_{k,j}\right) 
    + \sum_{k=1}^n \sum_{\ell=1}^n \left(B_{i,k} C_{k,\ell} A_{\ell,j} 
    + A_{i,k} B_{k,\ell} C_{\ell,j}\right)
    + A_{i,j} 
   &= 2 Y_{1,i,j} + [i=j] \\
      \sum_{k=1}^n A_{i,k} B_{k,j} 
    + \sum_{k=1}^n \sum_{\ell=1}^n \left(B_{i,k} C_{k,\ell} B_{\ell,j} 
    + A_{i,k} B_{k,\ell} D_{\ell,j}\right)
   &= 2 Y_{2,i,j} \\
      \sum_{k=1}^n C_{i,k} A_{k,j} 
    + \sum_{k=1}^n \sum_{\ell=1}^n \left(D_{i,k} C_{k,\ell} A_{\ell,j} 
    + C_{i,k} B_{k,\ell} C_{\ell,j}\right)
   &= 2 Y_{3,i,j} \\
      \sum_{k=1}^n \sum_{\ell=1}^n \left(D_{i,k} C_{k,\ell} B_{\ell,j} 
    + C_{i,k} B_{k,\ell} D_{\ell,j}\right)
   &= 2 Y_{4,i,j} + [i=j]
\end{align}
These can be linearized by replacing each product with a new binary variable, together with additional linear constraints, as shown in https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/37/how-to-linearize-the-product-of-two-binary-variables

---

As requested, here is the SAS code.  The NOOBJ option specifies that there is no objective, and the LINEARIZE option [automatically performs the linearization](https://go.documentation.sas.com/?cdcId=pgmsascdc&cdcVersion=v_010&docsetId=casmopt&docsetTarget=casmopt_optmodel_details57.htm&locale=en).

```
proc optmodel;
   num n = 4;
   set ROWS = 1..n;
   set COLS = ROWS;
   set CELLS = ROWS cross COLS;

   var A {CELLS} binary;
   var B {CELLS} binary;
   var C {CELLS} binary;
   var D {CELLS} binary;

   var Y {1..4, CELLS} >= 0 integer;

   /* A^2 + BC + BCA + ABC + A = I_4 */
   con Con1 {<i,j> in CELLS}:
      sum {k in 1..n} A[i,k]*A[k,j] 
    + sum {k in 1..n} B[i,k]*C[k,j] 
    + sum {k in 1..n, l in 1..n} B[i,k]*C[k,l]*A[l,j] 
    + sum {k in 1..n, l in 1..n} A[i,k]*B[k,l]*C[l,j]
    + A[i,j] 
   = 2*Y[1,i,j] + (i=j);

   /* AB + BCB + ABD = 0 */
   con Con2 {<i,j> in CELLS}:
      sum {k in 1..n} A[i,k]*B[k,j] 
    + sum {k in 1..n, l in 1..n} B[i,k]*C[k,l]*B[l,j] 
    + sum {k in 1..n, l in 1..n} A[i,k]*B[k,l]*D[l,j]
   = 2*Y[2,i,j];

   /* CA + DCA + CBC = 0 */
   con Con3 {<i,j> in CELLS}:
      sum {k in 1..n} C[i,k]*A[k,j] 
    + sum {k in 1..n, l in 1..n} D[i,k]*C[k,l]*A[l,j] 
    + sum {k in 1..n, l in 1..n} C[i,k]*B[k,l]*C[l,j]
   = 2*Y[3,i,j];

   /* DCB + CBD = I_4 */
   con Con4 {<i,j> in CELLS}:
      sum {k in 1..n, l in 1..n} D[i,k]*C[k,l]*B[l,j] 
    + sum {k in 1..n, l in 1..n} C[i,k]*B[k,l]*D[l,j]
   = 2*Y[4,i,j] + (i=j);

   solve noobj linearize;

   print A;
   print B;
   print C;
   print D;
quit;
```

Another approach to this feasibility problem is to introduce nonnegative surplus and slack variables and minimize their use.  The original problem is feasible if and only if all surplus and slack variables are 0.

```
   var Surplus {1..4, CELLS} >= 0;
   var Slack   {1..4, CELLS} >= 0;

   min Infeasibility = sum {t in 1..4, <i,j> in CELLS} (Surplus[t,i,j] + Slack[t,i,j]);

   /* A^2 + BC + BCA + ABC + A = I_4 */
   con Con1 {<i,j> in CELLS}:
      sum {k in 1..n} A[i,k]*A[k,j] 
    + sum {k in 1..n} B[i,k]*C[k,j] 
    + sum {k in 1..n, l in 1..n} B[i,k]*C[k,l]*A[l,j] 
    + sum {k in 1..n, l in 1..n} A[i,k]*B[k,l]*C[l,j]
    + A[i,j] 
    - Surplus[1,i,j] + Slack[1,i,j]
   = 2*Y[1,i,j] + (i=j);

   /* AB + BCB + ABD = 0 */
   con Con2 {<i,j> in CELLS}:
      sum {k in 1..n} A[i,k]*B[k,j] 
    + sum {k in 1..n, l in 1..n} B[i,k]*C[k,l]*B[l,j] 
    + sum {k in 1..n, l in 1..n} A[i,k]*B[k,l]*D[l,j]
    - Surplus[2,i,j] + Slack[2,i,j]
   = 2*Y[2,i,j];

   /* CA + DCA + CBC = 0 */
   con Con3 {<i,j> in CELLS}:
      sum {k in 1..n} C[i,k]*A[k,j] 
    + sum {k in 1..n, l in 1..n} D[i,k]*C[k,l]*A[l,j] 
    + sum {k in 1..n, l in 1..n} C[i,k]*B[k,l]*C[l,j]
    - Surplus[3,i,j] + Slack[3,i,j]
   = 2*Y[3,i,j];

   /* DCB + CBD = I_4 */
   con Con4 {<i,j> in CELLS}:
      sum {k in 1..n, l in 1..n} D[i,k]*C[k,l]*B[l,j] 
    + sum {k in 1..n, l in 1..n} C[i,k]*B[k,l]*D[l,j]
    - Surplus[4,i,j] + Slack[4,i,j]
   = 2*Y[4,i,j] + (i=j);

   solve linearize;
```

To find more than one solution, you can use the [MAXPOOLSOLS= option](https://go.documentation.sas.com/?cdcId=pgmsascdc&cdcVersion=v_010&docsetId=casmopt&docsetTarget=casmopt_milpsolver_syntax02.htm&locale=en#casmopt.milpsolver.milpmaxpoolsols).

---

Here is an example of how you can manually linearize the first product:

```
   /* M[i,j,k] = A[i,k]*A[k,j] */
   var M {1..n, 1..n, 1..n} binary;
   con Mcon1 {i in 1..n, j in 1..n, k in 1..n}:
      M[i,j,k] <= A[i,k];
   con Mcon2 {i in 1..n, j in 1..n, k in 1..n}:
      M[i,j,k] <= A[k,j];
   con Mcon3 {i in 1..n, j in 1..n, k in 1..n}:
      M[i,j,k] >= A[i,k] + A[k,j] - 1;
```

You would then replace `A[i,k]*A[k,j]` with `M[i,j,k]` throughout the original nonlinear constraints.

You can optionally declare the new variables as `>= 0` rather than `binary`.

---

To exclude a given set of solutions, first read them in:

```
set SOLUTIONS;
num Asol {CELLS, SOLUTIONS};
num Bsol {CELLS, SOLUTIONS};
num Csol {CELLS, SOLUTIONS};
num Dsol {CELLS, SOLUTIONS};
read data out into SOLUTIONS=[_N_] 
  {i in 1..n, j in 1..n} <Asol[i,j,_N_]=col('A_'||i||''||j)> 
  {i in 1..n, j in 1..n} <Bsol[i,j,_N_]=col('B_'||i||''||j)>
  {i in 1..n, j in 1..n} <Csol[i,j,_N_]=col('C_'||i||''||j)>
  {i in 1..n, j in 1..n} <Dsol[i,j,_N_]=col('D_'||i||''||j)>;
```

Then impose a no-good constraint:

```
con NoGood {sol in SOLUTIONS}:
  sum {<i,j> in CELLS} (
     (if Asol[i,j,sol] = 0 then A[i,j] else 1 - A[i,j])
   + (if Bsol[i,j,sol] = 0 then B[i,j] else 1 - B[i,j])
   + (if Csol[i,j,sol] = 0 then C[i,j] else 1 - C[i,j])
   + (if Dsol[i,j,sol] = 0 then D[i,j] else 1 - D[i,j])
  ) >= 1;
```

Then call the solver:

```
solve noobj;
```

If you do this for the 148 solutions you found and the resulting solve comes back infeasible, then you have found all solutions.

Comment: Thank you very much @RobPratt. I have zero background in linear programming. But looks like this is a good approach to answer my problem. As I want to know all possible solutions, how would I know if I already have all possible solutions? And which software did you use to find the A,B,C,D that you gave in your answer?

Comment: I used SAS to find this solution.  Some solvers, including SAS, have an option to find all solutions, but it can take much longer than finding just one.

Comment: Hello! I've been studying this solution. May I ask why the $Y_{t,i,j}$'s are multiplied by 2? And what does $[i=j]$ mean?

Comment: Because being equal to $0\pmod 2$ means $2$ times an integer. The $[i=j]$ is Iverson bracket notation for $1$ if $i=j$ and $0$ otherwise.

Comment: This may be too much to ask, but how do I implement this problem in SAS? I recently installed SAS University. From the lp problems I saw from SAS blogs, there is always an objective function involved and the RHS of the constraints are always exact values but this is not the case here. Moreover, how do I ask the program to find all solutions? Thank you very much for all your help.

Comment: @MashedPotato I added the SAS code to my answer.

Comment: LINEARIZE is a relatively new option, and I suspect you ran an older version that does not support it. Did you get any errors in the log?

Comment: For the first code, it ran smoothly but gave a wrong result. The second code did not run and received errors. I used the SAS on demand for academics, is linearize not supported here?

Comment: No, LINEARIZE is supported only in SAS Viya as of 2020.1.1, released in December 2020.  But you can do the linearization manually as described in the link to OR StackExchange.

Comment: Okay, thank you so much. I’ll first try to linearize it manually

Comment: Hello! If I want to linearize $A[i,k]*A[k,j]$, I introduce a new variable $M[i,j,k]$ which is dependent on $i,j,k$. How should I define var M? I’m getting confused since I can’t make $M$ as cells since it depends on three parameters. Same with the $N[i,j,k,l]=B[i,k]*C[k,l]*A[l,j]$ which is dependent on four paramaters.

Comment: I added code to illustrate the manual linearization.

Comment: solve noobj linearize with milp / maxpoolsols=100;

Comment: May I ask what's wrong with my code (attached in the question)? It only returns one solution. I know there's more than one solution since we got different soultions. Is it also possible to make the code more efficient? It seems that arrangement of constraints matter. I experienced that SAS OnDemand for Academics session expires after 5 hours which means the time for running the code cannot last longer than 5 hours.

Comment: By default, MAXPOOLSOLS returns only the solutions that are in the pool at termination but does not alter the search to look for more.  Sorry that I didn’t mention this before. You should also use the option soltype=best.

Comment: Does that mean that my code is fine? Do I type it as solve noobj with milp/ maxpoolsols=100 option soltype=best;?

Comment: Yes, your manual linearization looks correct, and the resulting numbers of variables, constraints, and constraint coefficients match the automated linearization.  The correct syntax is: solve noobj with milp / maxpoolsols=100 soltype=best;

Comment: I just tried it now, and it said that it found 100 solutions (I did not expect it to be this many) but it is only displaying one {A,B,C,D}. Where can I access the other solutions?

Comment: That probably means there are actually more, which you can get by setting maxpoolsols to a value higher than 100. You can create a SAS data set with all solutions by using this statement:    create data out(drop=s) from [s]=(1.._NSOL_)
      {i in 1..n, j in 1..n}
      <col('A_'||i||'_'||j)=A[i,j].sol[s]>
      {i in 1..n, j in 1..n}
      <col('B_'||i||'_'||j)=B[i,j].sol[s]>
      {i in 1..n, j in 1..n}
      <col('C_'||i||'_'||j)=C[i,j].sol[s]>
      {i in 1..n, j in 1..n}
      <col('D_'||i||'_'||j)=D[i,j].sol[s]>;

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/123071/discussion-between-mashed-potato-and-robpratt).

Comment: Hello! I set maxpoolsols=200 and it only reached 148 before my session expired (6 hours). Is it safe to say that the total number of solutions is around that number?

Comment: No, that is not a safe conclusion.  But you can check it by solving without maxpoolsols and with a "no-good" constraint for each of the 148 solutions.  I'll update my answer.

Comment: Do I put the no-good constraint after the solve noobj with milp/ maxpoolsols=200 soltype=best;?

Comment: No, this should be a separate run, for which you first read the 148 solutions from the previously generated output data set.

Comment: I had put the code in the chat, but I think you missed it.  I added to my answer just now.

Comment: Hello is my understanding correct? I will put the set SOLUTIONS and no-good constraint after the create data out(drop=s) statement? I get an error that says s is unknown. Thank you

Comment: Please see the chat.

Comment: Hello! Sorry to ask you once again. I edited my question and asked something. Thank you so much.

Comment: Hello, may I ask if the the code runs faster with the linearize function than the manual linearization? And does licensed SAS Viya have time limit? I noticed that I cannot really get all solutions because of the time limit. Thank you so much

Comment: The automated linearization yields the same variables and constraints as in your manual linearization.  To possibly speed things up, you might try relaxing the added binary variables to >= 0.  The solver itself has no time limit unless you specify the MAXTIME= option.  Your SAS Viya installation might have a time limit per user, so please check with your sysadmin.

Answer (score 1):

Here are two simplifications:

1. Up to similarity, there are only six choices of $D$. Note that the fourth equation is a Sylvester equation of the form $DX+XD=I$. By considering the Jordan form of $D$ over the algebraic closure of $\mathbb Z_2=GF(2)$, we see that $DX+XD=I$ is solvable only if all Jordan blocks of $D$ have even sizes. It follows that the characteristic polynomial $p(x)$ of $D$ can always be factorised as
   $$
   p(x)=(x+\lambda)^2(x+\mu)^2
   =(x^2+\lambda^2)(x^2+\mu^2)
   =x^4+(\lambda^2+\mu^2)x^2+\lambda^2\mu^2.\tag{$\ast$}
   $$
   Since $p$ has coefficients in $GF(2)$, there are only four possible choices of $p$, namely $x^4,\,x^2(x+1)^2,\,(x+1)^4$ or $x^4+x^2+1$. In other words, up to similarity, we can always assume that $D$ is equal to one of the five Jordan forms
   $$
   J_4(0),\,\pmatrix{J_2(0)\\ &J_2(0)},\,\pmatrix{J_2(0)\\ &J_2(1)}\,\pmatrix{J_2(1)\\ &J_2(1)}\, J_4(1)
   $$
   (where $J_m(\lambda)$ denotes the $m\times m$ Jordan block with eigenvalue $\lambda$) or the companion matrix
   $$
   \pmatrix{0&0&0&1\\ 1&0&0&0\\ 0&1&0&1\\ 0&0&1&0}.
   $$
2. You may replace $D$ by $D+I$. With the new $D$, the first and the forth equations then remain unchanged, but the second and the third equations become
   \begin{cases}
   BCB+ABD=0,\\
   DCA+CBC=0,\\
   \end{cases}
   which involve fewer summands.

There are also three observations of which I don't know the usefulness. First, (with the old $D$ or the new $D$) the second and the third equations together give the Sylvester equation $D(CAB)+(CAB)D=0$. Second, the second or the third equation implies that at least one of $B$ or $C$ is necessarily singular when one of $A$ or $D$ is singular. Finally, the LHS of the first equation can be rewritten as
$$
(I+A)A+A(I+BC)+(I+BC)(I+A)=0,
$$
where the LHS is a cyclic sum.

Answer (score 0):

I have made an algebraic attempt that might help you somewhere. Lets start with the second and third equation:
$$AB(I+D) = -BCB \rightarrow AB = -BCB(I+D)^{-1}$$
$$(I+D)CA = -CBC \rightarrow CA = -(I+D)^{-1}CBC$$
Now plug these results in the first equation:
$$A^2 + BC - B(I+D)^{-1}CBC - BCB(I+D)^{-1}C+A = I$$
From this, two things can be observed:
$$A = -B(I+D)^{-1}C, ~~ \text{and} ~~  BCA = ABC$$
Next, lets postmultiply the second equation with $C$ and the premultiply the third with $B$:
$$ABC + BCBC + ABDC = 0, ~~ BCA + BDCA + BCBC = 0$$
$$BCA + BDCA + BCBC = ABC + BCBC + ABDC \rightarrow BDCA = ABDC$$
Now if we substitute the definition for $A$ in this result the following can also be deduced:
$$BDCA = ABDC \rightarrow -BDCB(I+D)^{-1}C = -B(I+D)^{-1}CBDC$$
$$DCB(I+D)^{-1}=(I+D)^{-1}CBD$$
All these commutations are starting me to believe that $A$ is something like $\alpha I$, and therefore $-(I+D)^{-1} = \alpha (CB)^{-1}$. Hope this does help you get to an answer.

Comment: If $A=\alpha I$ then $A=0$ or $A=I$, as we are working over $\Bbb{F}_2$. But both are impossible.

Comment: Thanks for this!  But how do we know that $(I+D)^{-1}$ exists?